# LWJGL FPS Drop When Loading Textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Currently i'm using LWJGL to make a 2D game. But I've run into an issue. I am trying to make an "infinite world" but an issue comes up because if I create a lot of objects the frames drop and I believe it has to do with the amount of textures being loaded to objects. 
Currently I'm creating my world in a grid fashion like this

```
for(int x = -WORLDWIDTH; x < WORLDWIDTH; x+= BW)
{
    for(int y = -WORLDHEIGHT; y < WORLDHEIGHT; y += BH)
    {
        Tile newTile = new Tile(x,y,BW,BH,TileType.Grass);
        tiles.add(newTile);
    }
}
```

Where BW and BH are the block width and height. I try to keep texture loading to only objects on screen using this if statement

```
if(x >= 0-BW && x + width < WIDTH+BW && y >= 0-BH && y+ height < HEIGHT+BH)
{
    DrawQuadTexRotate(getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getWidth(),getHeight(),angle);
}
```

To load textures I do this

```
public static void DrawQuadTexRotate(Texture tex, float x, float y, float width, float height, float angle)
{
    tex.bind();
    glTranslatef(x + width / 2, y + height / 2, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0 ,0 , 1);
    glTranslatef(- width / 2, - height / 2, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex2f(width,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f(width,height);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex2f(0,height);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}

    public static Texture LoadTexture(String path, String fileType)
    {
        Texture tex = null;
        InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return tex;
    }
```

The Tile class basically has methods to do certain things based on what type it is. It holds the width, height, x, y and texture which my DrawQuadTex method uses

Here is the tile class

```
public class Tile {
public float x, y, width, height, angle;
private Texture texture;
private TileType type;
public long timeStart = 0;
public int filled = 1;
public int power = 0;
public int transmitPower = 0;
int connected = 0;
public boolean moveRight,moveLeft,moveUp,moveDown,moveAngle;

public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height,TileType type)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.type = type;
    this.texture = QuickLoad(type.textureName);
    timeStart = Timer.getTime();
    updateType();
    updateFill();
}
public void draw()
{
    if(x >= 0-BW && x + width < WIDTH+BW && y >= 0-BH && y+ height < HEIGHT+BH)
    {
        DrawQuadTexRotate(getTexture(), getX(), getY(), getWidth(),getHeight(),angle);
    }
}
public void addFood()
{
    if(this.type == TileType.Farm && filled == 1)
    {
        long timing = Timer.getTime();
        if(timing >= (timeStart + 10000))
        {
            Values.food += (1+Artist.riverAmount);
            timeStart = timing;
        }
    }
}
public void mineOre()
{
    if(this.type == TileType.Mine && filled == 1)
    {
        long timing = Timer.getTime();
        if(timing >= (timeStart + 20000))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size();i++)
            {
                if(tiles.get(i).getType() == TileType.Ore)
                {
                    tiles.get(i).setType(TileType.LandTile);
                    Values.oreAmount += 1;
                    timeStart = timing;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void move()
{
    if(moveRight == true)
    {
        x -= 10;
    }
    if(moveLeft == true)
    {
        x += 10;
    }
    if(moveUp == true)
    {
        y += 10;
    }
    if(moveDown == true)
    {
        y -= 10;
    }
}
public void testPower()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        if(tiles.get(i).x >= x - BW && tiles.get(i).x <= x + BW && tiles.get(i).y >= y - BH && tiles.get(i).y <= y + BH && tiles.get(i).getType() == TileType.Wire && tiles.get(i).transmitPower == 1 && type == TileType.HomeBasic)
        {
            power = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            power = 0;
        }

        if(tiles.get(i).x >= x - BW && tiles.get(i).x <= x + BW && tiles.get(i).y >= y - BH && tiles.get(i).y <= y + BH && (tiles.get(i).transmitPower == 1 || tiles.get(i).type == TileType.PowerPlant) && type == TileType.Wire)
        {
            transmitPower = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if(tiles.get(i).type == TileType.Wire && tiles.get(i).transmitPower == 0)
        {
            transmitPower = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            transmitPower = 0;
        }
    }
}
public void updateFill()
{
    if(type == TileType.HomeBasic || type == TileType.Farm || type == TileType.Mine)
    {
        filled = 0;
    }
}
public void stats()
{
    if(type == TileType.HomeBasic)
    {
        //wt.drawString((int)x, (int)(y-25), Integer.toString(filled), Color.white);
    }
}
public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Texture getTexture() {
    return texture;
}

public void setTexture(Texture texture) {
    this.texture = texture;
}

public TileType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(TileType type) {
    this.type = type;
    updateType();
}
public void updateType()
{
    this.texture = QuickLoad(type.textureName);
    timeStart = Timer.getTime();
    updateFill();
}
```

}

```
    public static Texture QuickLoad(String name)
{
    Texture tex = null;
    tex = LoadTexture("res/" + name + ".png", "PNG");
    return tex;
}
```

So how would I go about trying to fix this?

Comment: What is Tile class? How do you load textures? How do you render? Your question does not include any opengl/lwjgl code.  Please edit so your question contains all the possibly relevant part of your code.

Comment: Sorry ive added that to my question now.

Comment: Could you share the Tile class also?

Comment: Added that as well

Comment: Instead of loading the (same) textures for each tile, you should load it once (at startup) and pass around a reference or index to that texture (edit: I guess you're doing that in `QuickLoad`?) Also try to generate your world in batches that you work on asynchronously - load balancing those batches will help you avoid frame drops.

Comment: Sorry just added the QuickLoad method code

Comment: So BeyelerStudios is basically answered your question, this is why I wanted to see your Tile class. Do not load the same texture for every tile again and again. To be clear your QuickLoad method should only called Once! for each texture. You can load your texture before you create tiles and pass those textures references to new Tiles.

Comment: I have just changed my code to make sure QuickLoad only runs once per texture and I pass around the texture to each tile but the fps is still bad. Im not sure what I have to do now to fix this.